# Mongoose batch nested objects insert

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, batch-processing

I have a array of objects with deep nested arrays of objects like so:

```
[{
  "clause": "7",
    "section": [{
      "name": "whatever",
      "subClauses": [{
      "name": "foo",
      "details": [{
        "detail": "bar"
      }]
    }]
  }]
}]
```

Each array has several items in it. In my Mongoose schemas, the subdocuments are individual collections, ie nested Model.schema.

Is it possible to set up the Mongoose Schema to do a bulk `Model.collection.insert` that creates _id fields for each sub document?

Comment: Would you like to break the data in different collections? i.e.: sections in the sections collections, clauses in clauses collection etc. Also, should the common data still be part of the element? i.e.: the clause field should appear for all the inserts

Comment: Yes sorry I should have mentioned that the subdocuments have their own collections, but the seed data I am drawing from is one huge json file! I currently am seeding the db by looping through the arrays and creating new Model() functions and pushing each in manually which seems messy.

Comment: How are the collections broken down? For example, the document that goes into the `sections` collection should contain the other arrays as they are? Or should all the documents be flattened out? i.e.: if you have 10 `subClauses` for a section, you will have 10 different entries in the `sections` collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that Model.collection.insert does not create an _id for sub documents, whereas Model.create() does. I've found however that although Model.create will give _Ids to each sub doc, it will not save the sub doc individually to the database, meaning that if I called SubDoc.find({}), nothing would be returned...